# Android 9patch image

Tags: android, android-layout, nine-patch

When 9patch png images are used, do we need to provide them in xhdpi, hdpi and mdpi format also or only one resolution is enough? Because either way they will resize on resolution... or am I thinking something wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use different sizes, otherwise a border on a LDPI device would look much thicker than on an XHDPI device

Comment: Yes, but this border isn't re-sized according to the current dpi?

Comment: As far as I know, it isn't. The best practice is to include drawables for each pixel density.

Answer (score 2):

For the Nine patch image only one resolution is enough because 9-patch image scales the image text according to the layouts...

Answer (score 0):

Nine-patches are widely used for background kind of images: most typically it would be some sort of border and a fill. You should provide only one resolution of 9patch, Android would scale it appropriately.

Comment: Are you sure, 9patch also downsizes an image? If it is not, you could only provide the smallest resolution and the up-scaled image would not look very nice.

Comment: so the resolution for xhdpi should be ok as the other ones will be scalled down and look ok?